# Getting error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1, what could be wrong?

Tags: php, sql, row

I'm trying to make a form page where the user can upload a list of parameters via radio buttons. I've taken great care not to missnumber anything, yet still i get the error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1, what could be wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Add Videos</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

$DisplayForm = TRUE;

//Database Connection Information
$server_connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") 
  or die("Cannot Connect to Server: " . mysql_error($server_connection));  
$db_connection = mysql_select_db("database",$server_connection)
  or die("Cannot Connect to Database: " . mysql_error($db_connection));  

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$sql = "INSERT INTO main (

lin, tit, hco, hle, eth,
age, pra, bea, cto, ctc, 
cbo, cbc, foo, fco, eoc, 

fbo, #gi, loc, fil, hei, 
msi, lea, abs, bic, boo,
bac, che, leg, tri, vas,

ifa, atw, equ, aos, ato, 
afo, sea, pro, fn,  ln, 
fn2, ln2, mak
) 

VALUES(
'$_POST[path]','$_POST[path]','$_POST[hcol]','$_POST[hlen]','$_POST[race]',
'$_POST[old]', '$_POST[win]', '$_POST[hot]', '$_POST[shir]','$_POST[tcol]',
'$_POST[bott]','$_POST[bcol]','$_POST[shoe]','$_POST[scol]','$_POST[effe]',

'$_POST[bpar]','$_POST[num]', '$_POST[loc]', '$_POST[webc]','$_POST[hei]',
'$_POST[musc]','$_POST[lean]','$_POST[stom]','$_POST[bic]', '$_POST[bob]',
'$_POST[labs]','$_POST[pebs]','$_POST[lebs]','$_POST[trbs]','$_POST[vein]',

'$_POST[inte]','$_POST[actw]','$_POST[equi]','$_POST[shof]','$_POST[oth]',
'$_POST[wor]', '$_POST[seb]', '$_POST[sebt]','$_POST[fn]',  '$_POST[ln]',
'$_POST[fn2]', '$_POST[ln2]', '$_POST[wat]'
)";

//Perform ADD
if(!mysql_query($sql,$server_connection)){
echo "Could not add data to database: " . mysql_error($server_connection);
}
else{
    echo "Thank you, please check myPHPadmin";
}

//Close Connection
mysql_close($server_connection);

$DisplayForm = FALSE;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem in your values, use `$_POST['path']` instead of `$_POST[path]`.

You need use **'path'** unless you defined **path** as a constant variable before.

Comment: I get an error when I do that.  I've tried 
'$_POST[path]'
'$_POST['path']'
$_POST['path']
they're not working.  Not missing any commas or apostraphies as much as i can tell.  There's 43 columns and 43 values. I'm at a loss....

Comment: Change `fbo, #gi, loc, fil, hei, ` by `fbo, gi, loc, fil, hei, `, it's the problem